# How can I read an unlimited string until EOF and put them a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

For example, user entered 3 lines entry and I want to split them as a word and store them in char array.

Entry:

```
  Banana apple kiwi cherry\n
  horse car blue jacket\n
  bla bla bla  ^d
```

The entry maybe include more or less lines. I don't know how many words in the entry. I only know that entry end with EOF and I need to store all words in an array. Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: You can use `getc()` to read a character and `realloc()` to allocate more memory if needed.

Comment: I'm beginner in c i don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    char *big=malloc(256);
    int c; long n=0,t=255;
    printf("Enter something very long: ");
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if (n>=t) {
            big=realloc(big,t+256);
            t+=256;
        }
        big[n]=c; ++n;
    }
    big[n]='\0';
    puts(big); // using puts as it's faster than printf
    // or printf("%s",big);
    free(big);
    return 0;
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but there are some problems. It should be `int c;` because `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. You need to capture the return value from `realloc()`. You are not allocating more space with `realloc()` — the second argument is the new size, not an increment to the size. You should probably use `big[n]` instead of `*(big+n)`.  Using `puts()` means you get a stray extra newline in the output compared with the input. It's generally better to have just one statement per line. Why not initialize `n` in its declaration — like you did `t`? Mishandling of `realloc()` is bad!

Comment: Better, but the `realloc()` should be `big = realloc(big, t + 256); t += 256;`.

Comment: Thanks all, I've been writing this in a hurry. This worked for me, maybe the compiler's drunk, who knows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Isn't `big=realloc(big,t+=256);` better?

Comment: @CoolGuy: sorta, but not if you error check the allocation, which hasn't been discussed yet.  There's also the `ptr = realloc(ptr, size)` mis-pattern too that should be discussed.  Yes, `t += 256` would work.  It isn't the way I'd write it, though.  I calculate a new size, try to allocate it, and only when the allocation is successful do I set the current size of the allocated memory to the new size (along with setting the current pointer to the new pointer).  And yes, you can recover from the incremented size on failure by decrementing the size afterwards if need be.